# problem with compiling in latex

Tags: texmaker

I have a problem with compiling latex files: in particular i have always this error:

```
Impossible to execute the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I have ubuntu 14.04 and latex 2013. times ago I did the upgrade from ubuntu 12 to ubuntu 14.04.
I'm using texmaker as editor.

can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: looks like wrong path setting or a missing TeXLive installation.  Try `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

Comment: I have install texlive-full but the problem still persists.. seems that the compiler doesnt' launch..

Comment: Open a terminal and insert `which pdflatex`. If you have no output then the path for the binaries is not correct.

Comment: i have this path after the command which pdflatex:    /usr/bin/pdflatex

Comment: then run in a terminal a testfile with `pdflatex test.tex`. If it works well, then have a look into your editor if a path is defined for the programs. It may be wrong. Delete any path setting. I suppose you are using texmaker or texstudio. The setting is available via `options->configure`

Comment: I have this:                                                                                           This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!

Comment: your tex installation  is not correct. Try `sudo fmtutil-sys --all`. If it doesn't help, then remove and reinstall texlive-full.

Comment: I have removed and installed texlive but unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: I suppose that there are some old files from a preceding installation on your machine.

Comment: Did you manage it by now?